# Azure microsoft graph api invited user not able to invite user

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working on an app where i have some users on azure ad and some users need to be externals(ex:gmail).Iam using microsoft graph api to invite users from external. All these users are have user administrator role in AD.
I am able to invite external user successfully with internal user credentials. But when i try to invite external user again with the invited user details i am getting 
error : 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Current authenticated context is not valid for this request. This occurs when a request is made to an endpoint that requires user sign-in. For example, /me requires a signed-in user.  Acquire a token on behalf of a user to make requests to these endpoints.  Use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for mobile and native apps and the OAuth 2.0 implicit flow for single-page web apps.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2d6d6c29-4f13-4eeb-bae4-2d6cc0d2de00",
            "date": "2019-05-27T13:22:20"
        }
    }
}

I am using postman to check these apis.I have attached the request details to get the jwt token.Can you please help here. Let me know if you need more info. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue if I add Google as an identity provider for B2B guest users.

[image]

I have also tried with [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=$batch&method=POST&version=beta). We can not even use this tool since the google account is not a microsoft account.

Maybe the only way to invite another guest user with the **invited google account**(isn't a microsoft account) is using Azure portal.

Google guest users must sign in using a link that includes the tenant context (for example, `https://myapps.microsoft.com/?tenantid=<tenant id>` or `https://portal.azure.com/<tenant id>`

Comment: Thanks for the response Tony Ju. I already had permissions but for the safe side I pressed the grant consent button and tested. Still the same issue. 
I have federeated google in azure active directory so that when we invite user on gmail,it wont create an account and no need to setup password.
We can simply use gmail original credentials. Are you also doing this or is it asking to create account for you when user is invited url redeemed?

Comment: @bhaskar I didn't use federeated google with aad. But I will not need to create an new account. I can login in with the original credentials. Just like new a guest user in  azure portal.

Comment: You can add a guest user(gmail account) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/add-users-administrator

Comment: Hi Tony,I tried if we dont use federated it will create account in Microsoft account. We can cross verify if the users source from active directory users page. I can see mine source is google.Can you pls cross verify that

Comment: @bhaskar Yes, you are right. The source will be Microsoft Account. So you need the the source to be google, right?

Comment: yes.if source is Microsoft account means it is created an account.It should be google the we can verify this issue

Comment: No Tony,If we the is user is google federated he will not be able to login to portal at all.

Comment: @bhaskar You can. You need to login in with a link that includes the tenant context. Try portal.azure.com/<tenant id>. Replace tenant id with your value.

Comment: @bhaskar tenant id is your directory id.

Comment: You are correct Tony.But for my solution I need to invite using graph apis from app.